# Sub menus are not showing

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have made a menu where data comes from database.I need to see second level and third level menus but the problem is  **sub menus are not showing**. only shows the first level.

I have added css and php code.

Plz check Menu picture:

[image: menu picture]

php code:

```
<?php

function display_children($parent, $level) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "nfs";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT a.cat_id, a.product, a.category_link, Deriv1.Count FROM `category` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `category` GROUP BY parent_id) Deriv1 ON a.cat_id = Deriv1.parent_id WHERE a.parent_id=" . $parent);
    echo "<nav><ul class='nav'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
            echo "<li><a href='" . $row['category_link'] . "'>" . $row['product'] . "</a>";
            display_children($row['cat_id'], $level + 1);
            echo "</li>";
        } elseif ($row['Count']==0) {
            echo "<li><a href='" . $row['category_link'] . "'>" . $row['product'] . "</a></li>";
        } else;
    }
    echo "</ul><nav>";
}
echo display_children(0, 1);
?>
```

Comment: side note - since you use `echo` throughout your function, using `echo` in `echo display_children(0, 1);` is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: have you looked at the html source code to see if the sub menus are there and it is just not displaying? Have you checked if your query works to return sub menu rows?

Comment: You did not indicate your 2nd and 3rd level....beside they need to be in different loop and in different <li></li>

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is not true.
Use this function to counting the number rows.
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count>0) {
..............
}

Comment: The OPs if statement is checking the value of `Deriv1.Count`, not the row count.